# How to create an InfoWindowAdapter for clusterManager.clusterMarkerCollection in Kotlin?

Tags: android

I've implemented a map activity that displays clusters as well as individual items.

When a Cluster is clicked on, I'd like to display (in the InfoWindow) a list of all the Markers contained within that Cluster.

The problem is that ClusterInfoWindowAdapter's Interface has MARKERs as the first parameter, not my custom InfoItem.

How do people workaround this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit late to answer, but this link was helpful: https://medium.com/@CayugaSoft/work-with-clustermanager-901600a2194f

I don't know much about your implementation, but here are the basics of how I got mine to work:

- In the class that inherits from DefaultClusterRenderer, you can override onClusterItemRendered, onClusterRendered and onClusterUpdated.  All three of these methods have "marker: Marker" as an input parameter
- In each of these methods, I set the tag of the marker to be either the cluster (Cluster) or your own custom item (in my case MarkerClusterItem).

```
override fun onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem: MarkerClusterItem, marker: Marker) {
    super.onClusterItemRendered(clusterItem, marker)
    marker.tag = clusterItem
}
```

or

```
   override fun onClusterRendered(cluster: Cluster<MarkerClusterItem>, marker: Marker) {
        super.onClusterRendered(cluster, marker)
        marker.tag = cluster
    }
```

- Next you create your Custom info window adapter. You extract the marker tag, inspect it for the type of object (which is either your custom object or a cluster of) and lay out your view accordingly.  Below the views are simple, but you can make them as complex as you like.

```
class MyMapInfoWindowAdapter(private val context: Context) : GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter {

    override fun getInfoContents(p0: Marker): View? {

        //we put the actual cluster item or cluster itself in the marker tag
        return when (p0.tag){
            is MarkerClusterItem -> {
                inflateViewForItem(p0.tag as MarkerClusterItem)
            }
            is Cluster<*> -> {
                inflateViewForCluster((p0.tag as Cluster<MarkerClusterItem>))
            }
            else -> null
        }
    }

    override fun getInfoWindow(p0: Marker): View? {
        return null //returning null here will ensure getInfoContents is Called
    }

    private fun inflateViewForCluster(withCluster: Cluster<MarkerClusterItem>): View?{
        val inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cluster_layout, null)
        inflatedView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.layout_title)?.text = "Cluster"
        inflatedView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.layout_snippet)?.text = "${withCluster.items.count()} items"
        return inflatedView
    }

    private fun inflateViewForItem(withItem: MarkerClusterItem): View? {
        val inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_layout, null)
        inflatedView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.layout_title)?.text = withItem.title
        inflatedView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.layout_snippet)?.text = withItem.snippet
        return inflatedView
    }
}
```

- Next, tell the cluster manager about your info window adapter.  After instantiating your cluster manager, you can set the info window adapter.

```
mClusterManager = ClusterManager(context.applicationContext, gMap)
mClusterManager.markerCollection.setInfoWindowAdapter(MyMapInfoWindowAdapter(context.applicationContext))
```

- Last step, set the info window adapter on your google map.

```
gMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(mClusterManager.markerManager)
```

To listen for info window clicks, you can set the info window click listener on the class that inherits from DefaultClusterRenderer as well.